# RaspberryPi plus VNC plus Ubuntu gets stuck

Tags: raspberrypi, vnc

[this is a repeat, my apologies; I posted it under the Ubuntu list of the raspberrypi.com forum before I found the "Not official" note there]

Hi.  I'd like to set up a RaspberryPi machine for desktop use, while at the same time, help the user from a remote location if necessary.  To do that, I want the remote and local sessions to be as identical as possible.

On the stock Raspberry Pi OS, VNC runs easily.  The VNC server runs, remote connections start as I'd expect.

Meanwhile on an Ubuntu PC, VNC also works fine; here's the full ~/.vnc/xserver I'm using:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
/usr/bin/gnome-session
```

Lately under Ubuntu I did have to add those two 'unset' entries, thanks Google, but otherwise, no trouble.

But, if I have the RP4 running Ubuntu, vncserver will run, but doesn't start the window manager, with or without either of those two 'unset' calls.  A VNC session does connect as expected, but what we see is the blank black and white checkerboard with the black "X" floating around.

Some additions:

```
$ lsb_release -a No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 23.04 Release: 23.04 Codename: lunar
```

```
$ uname -a Linux sal9 6.2.0-1013-raspi #15-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Sep 8 18:53:11 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

That's the latest version of Ubuntu offered in the official RaspberryPi.com 'Imager' app.

And, some progress: I found that, on my RP4 Ubuntu, I've been running the 'tightvncserver' package, while the desktop instance has 'tigervnc-standalone-server' installed.  Adding the 'standalone' package on the RP4 did make progress.

Now, when I start the server, it does start 'gnome-session-binary', with a list of processes offered to call.

But that's configured differently than what we see at the RP's desktop session.  The background is plain blue, whereas the system's desktop comes up with a picture, and the button list is on the bottom; system's desktop setup comes up on the left-hand side.  So, I'm guessing there's still a config setting I haven't found yet.

Still looking; hints appreciated, but at least I'm not stuck as I was when I posted this, so thanks for the hints.

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details. Which Ubuntu product & release are you using?  What did you install?  Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? or a Ubuntu Desktop image? and which version of that *unstated* product?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Please add additional details to your questions; no release is mentioned in the question itself (*this is a Q&A site, and answers will be to the question itself, not to comments made by readers to the the OP/Original-Poster or earlier commentators*) ; this isn't a forum; comments will get removed/cleaned once addressed.